# How to put the official google +1 and facebook like/share button in the same line?

Tags: javascript, css, button, web, share

I don't know what's the reason why don't want to put them in a single line, which will waste my space, I want to put them in the same line but not using 3-party buttons, the only method I can use is table, but will be not responsive, please help, thanks!

Comment: Have you considered not having these buttons, which no one likes and which spy on people?

Comment: I don't consider that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image: Demo]

1. Wrap the buttons in `<div>`s and make the style `display:inline-block;`
2. Make sure the parent style has `font-size:0px`, or else the facebook icons will be out of place.

Here's the code, starting from `<body>`:

```
<body>
  <!-- Buttons -->
  <div class="sharing-buttons" style="font-size:0px">
    <div style="margin-right: 4px; display:inline-block;">
      <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
      <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://benzhang.xyz" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=809268315782757";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</body>
```

Feel free to comment if any clarification is needed.